# On the complex roots of $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0=0$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

> Suppose that the coefficients of the equation $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+...+a_1x+a_0=0$ are real and satisfy $0<a_0 \leq a_1 \leq \dotsb \leq a_{n-1} \leq 1$. Let $z$ be a complex root of the equation with $\lvert z \rvert \geq 1$. Show that $z^{n+1}=1$.

This question seems very hard for me and I don’t know where to start.

Edit:
From the post: [$x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0=0$ has real coefficients which satisfy $0<a_0 \le a_1 \le \cdots \le a_{n-1} \le 1$ prove that $z$ is a root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584602/xna-n-1xn-1-cdots-a-1xa-0-0-has-real-coefficients-which-satisfy-0a?rq=1)

I found the solution by Mr. Y, but he did not legally prove the question, and the only answer is too hard for me to understand.

Comment: Hint: multiply by $z-1$ pass all the terms except $z^{n+1}$ to the right and use that $|z^k| \le |z^n|, 0 \le k \le n$ since $|z| \ge 1$ and the triangle inequality to get $|z^{n+1}| \le |z^n|$ conclude that $|z|=1$ and all $a$'s are $1$

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Possibly similar to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584602/xna-n-1xn-1-cdots-a-1xa-0-0-has-real-coefficients-which-satisfy-0a?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots +a_1x+a_0=0$ has real coefficients which satisfy $0&lt;a_0 \le a_1 \le \cdots \le a_{n-1} \le 1$ prove that $z$ is a root](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1584602/xna-n-1xn-1-cdots-a-1xa-0-0-has-real-coefficients-which-satisfy-0a)

Comment: Hmm.. the proof in the duplicate is incomplete. It has shown $|x| = 1$ but not $x^{n+1} = 1$. To complete the proof, use the fact for $p,q\in \mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$, $|p + q| = |p| + |q|$ implies $p/q$ is real and positive. Using this, you can deduce the terms on RHS of
$$x^{n+1} = (1-a_{n-1})x^n + (a_{n-1} - a_{n-2})x^{n-1} + \cdots + (a_1 - a_0)x + a_0$$
are all non-negative. So
$$x^{n+1} = (1-a_{n-1}) + (a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}) + \cdots + (a_1 - a_0) + a_0  = 1$$

Comment: Hui, okay, thanks

Comment: Hello achille hui, sorry this is kinda late. But how did you prove that |p+q|=|p|+|q| when x is a complex number?